# How to correctly implement type `AList` for custom class `alist`, similiar to `List` and `list`

Tags: python, typing

How can I achieve the same with custom class `alist` and its type alias `AList` as how builtin `list` and `List` from `typing` work?

I can see that type `List` is defined following way in `typing`:
`List = _alias(list, 1, inst=False, name='List')`

`_alias` is alias for internal class `_SpecialGenericAlias` and AFAIK those should not be used externally.

I have now following code:

```py
import asyncio
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class alist(list, Generic[T]):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    async def __aiter__(self):
        for _ in self:
            yield _


AList = alist[T]


async def func(integers: AList[int]):
    async for integer in integers:
        print(integer)


asyncio.run(func(alist([1, 2, 3])))
```

Using VSCode and when hovering mouse on `integer` on line `async for integer in integers:` it shows "(variable) integer: Unknown". It leads me wonder if this will make auto completion tools and type checkers understand `AList` and `alist` correctly. Code runs without errors.

Comment: What if you define `alist` as `class alist(typing.List[T])`? Currently your `alist` is just a list of objects from the perspective of the interpreter/type checker. I can't reproduce the described behavior in VSCode, FWIW.

Comment: I have all the `list` auto complete functionality on `integers`, which is the actual `alist` (not `integer`).

Comment: There's really no need to do this. `List` was only added to the `typing` module because the built-in type `list` didn't support `__getitem__`, which was needed for the chosen implementation of generic types. Once `__class_getitem__` was added to the language, `list` *could* be used generically, and the need for `List` went away. `List` has been deprecated since Python 3.9, and will be removed eventually (though no earlier than October 2025, when Python 3.9 reaches end-of-life).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` itself is generic (since Python 3.9); just use

```
import asyncio
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")


class alist(list[T]):
    async def __aiter__(self):
        for _ in self:
            yield _


async def func(integers: alist[int]):
    async for integer in integers:
        print(integer)


asyncio.run(func(alist([1, 2, 3])))
```

`typing.List` is deprecated, an artifact of a time when the built-in types could not be used generically.

Comment: Leaving this here as a note. Typing aliases from typing that are deprecated starting from Python 3.9 https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#deprecated-typing-aliases